# Hibernate: Avoiding reading all the records to memory at once

Tags: java, nhibernate, hibernate

I have a large amount of rows in the database from which I need to create an XML document. I am using hibernate 3. The basic list() method in Criteria and Query interfaces looks dangerous: I quess it pretty much has to read all the records into memory even if I only iterate over them. Or is there some lazy loading magic? If not, I seem to have two options left: using scroll() or iterate() from Query (scroll is also present in Criteria). iterate doesn't look all that great either if I want to have minimal SQL roundtrips: "The first SQL query returns identifiers only". So am I right, do I have to use scroll() for this?

Comment: This stuff applied to NHibernate as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using scroll() in conjunction with this:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html

A command-oriented API for performing bulk operations against a database.

A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking, nor do operations cascade to associated instances. Collections are ignored by a stateless session. Operations performed via a stateless session bypass Hibernate's event model and interceptors. Stateless sessions are vulnerable to data aliasing effects, due to the lack of a first-level cache.

For certain kinds of transactions, a stateless session may perform slightly faster than a stateful session.

Answer (score 1):

Use the setMaxResults() method on Criteria.

```
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class);
crit.setMaxResults(maxResults);
crit.setFirstResult(firstResultIndex);
List cats = crit.list();
```

http://hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

Comment: What I want to do is have all the results out in transactional fashion. I gather that you mean I should  build the whole big resultset from parts. Can I use these to "stitch" my consistent, big resultset together so that I really get a snapshot from a certain point of time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "have all the results out in a transactional fashion".

Comment: What I mean is that my resultset is a snapshot, no writes/deletes which happen in between from other clients will affect that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to mark the objects off as procesed, you can simply use scroll() and evict the objects from the session as you are done with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm planning on doing:
Create a temporary table with the object IDs of all the rows I need to export:

```
Insert into BatchTable (ID, Seq) Select (O.ID, Sequence.Next) 
From MyObject O Where ...
```

In small units of work load in the objects:

```
Select Min(B.Seq), Max(B.Seq) From BatchTable;

for (batch = minBatch; batch <= maxBatch; batch += size) {
 beginTransaction();
 results = query("Select O From MyObject O, BatchTable B 
                  Where O.ID = B.ID and (? <= B.Seq AND B.Seq < ?)");

 exportXML(results);
 for (MyObject O : results) {
  O.setProcessed(True);
  O.update();
 }
 commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, have a look at batch fetching Section 19.1.4 and 19.1.5 should do.
http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins-forms

Comment: Do you know whether those batch-queries (e.g. 10, 10 and 5 cats in the example) end up all in the list (if I query the table with list() in memory while I iterate through it? Or can hibernate unload the first batch when I proceed to the next batch (e.g. the next 10 cats after the first 10 cats).